# how to get parent element from document object in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a problem with iframe.

I want to get parent objet or parent node from content of iframe.

my code :

a.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <input type="button" value="click me" onClick="parent.getIframe(document);"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

index.php :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var getIframe = function(obj){
   // Iframe Element = $(obj).parent();
   //or some things likes this.
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <div id="myId">
        <iframe src="a.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want when i click on "click me" button. I want to get HTMLIFRAME object elment by document object of iframe.

I need your help.

Comment: if i want to get id of div contains iframe("myId") when i click "click me" in a.html page, How must i do?

Comment: if i want to get id of div contains iframe("myId") when i click "click me" in a.html page, How must i do? Now my solution is compare with src attribute of iframe. But i don't want to use it. becuase in my page has so many iframe. It can be 50 or up 50 iframe => my program will be slowly. And i feel it's not good ideals. when click on "click me" button of a.html. we have document of page or contentDocument or contentWindow. Why don't we get Element IFrame by them. I need your help.

Comment: Sounds like you might be coming up against the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following two properties:

```
contentDocument - Returns the document object generated by a frame/iframe
contentWindow -   Returns the window object generated by a frame/iframe
```

Check [this reference](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1592-Getting-IFRAME-Window-And-Then-Document-References-With-contentWindow.htm)

Comment: thanks Anshu. But i want get element Iframe from contentDocument or contentWindow or document of iframe.Because i'm in a.html. so. I have them. i want to get element iframe from them.